# Android - view does not keep height

Tags: java, android, layout, view, android-viewgroup

I'm trying to add a custom view to a linearlayout, but the view does not keep it's height. The height is 48dp so it's fixed but after I do addView() it change to wrap_content :

```
LinearLayout cmsList = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.ll_cms_sections);

View group = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_cms_group, null);

cmsList.addView(group);
```

The **group** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="@color/clear_orange">

<com.dekibae.android.popinthecity.presentation.ui.widgets.FontText
    android:id="@+id/tv_cms"
    style="@style/TitleOrangexNormal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/indicator"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:text="TEST SECTION"
    app:font="@string/plaak" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/dropdown_arrow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The **cmsList**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_cms_sections"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

I even tried to force it :

```
group.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 48));
```

Comment: The height argument needs to be in pixels not dp.  So try `(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 48, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics())`

Comment: Yes you are the man !! Edit an answer i accept it !

Comment: You don't need to "force" anything. Just pass the parent `LinearLayout` in the `inflate()` call.

Comment: Actually @AbtinGramian found a solution that works, i'll try your idea too

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on @Abtin Gramian's comment the constructor used takes as a dimension pixels, and not dp (density independent pixels)
From the android documentation

> android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams public LayoutParams(int width,
>                       int height)
>
> Creates a new set of layout parameters with the specified width and height.
>
> Parameters:
>
> width - either WRAP_CONTENT, FILL_PARENT or a **fixed size in pixels**
>
> height - either
>   WRAP_CONTENT, FILL_PARENT or a **fixed size in pixels**

So through the use of

`public static float applyDimension (int unit, float value, DisplayMetrics metrics)`

we can make a conversion from a dimension in one type of metrics like `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP` to another, in this case one adequate for the current display.

```
group.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 48, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics())));
```

Comment: @An-droid have you been able to solve your problem? let me know if this helped =)